# When do matrices respect inequalities?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, inequality

Suppose I have vectors $u, v \in \mathbb{R}^n$ such that $u \le v$, meaning that, component-wise, each element of $u$ is less than or equal to the corresponding component in $v$.

I am curious about under what conditions real $n \times n$ matrices $M$ necessarily satisfy

$$M u \le M v$$

Clearly, diagonal matrices with positive diagonal coefficients work (for somewhat trivial reasons), but I feel as though there is a larger class of matrices that respects the inequality structure. I conjecture that matrices with all non-negative entries respect the inequality structure.

What I am curious about is if a set of matrices even larger than that can be considered.

Comment: It is not hard to prove that it works for matrices with non-negative entries. And also that it doesn't work for a matrix with a single negative entry. Just pick $v=2u$ with $u$ the vector with only zeros except for one one at the same position as the column for which the matrix has the negative entry.

Comment: This makes sense

Answer (score 1):

It shall be
$$
\left\{ {\matrix{
   {{\bf 0} \le {\bf M}\,\left( {{\bf v} - {\bf u}} \right) \le {\bf M}\,{\bf w}} \hfill & {\left| {\;0 \le w_{\,k} \;\left| {\;\forall k} \right.} \right.} \hfill  \cr 
   {{\bf M}\,{\bf w} < {\bf 0}} \hfill & {\left| {\;w_{\,k}  < 0\;\left| {\;\forall k} \right.} \right.} \hfill  \cr 
 } } \right.
$$

Then taking
$$
{\bf w} = \left( {0, \ldots ,0,1,0, \ldots ,0} \right)^T 
$$
the conclusion follows easily, as per Stan Tendijck comment.